# A generic testdata builder -- does it obscure the beauty of the pattern?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, moq

I have made a generic databuilder for unit test, because I got tired of implementing constructors and Build methods again and again. Does this obscure the beauty of the pattern (that I really DO love)?

Here is my generic builder (built in C# with Moq):

```
public class GenericMockBuilder<T> where T: class
{
    private readonly Mock<T> _objectMock = new Mock<T>(); 

    protected Mock<T> ObjectMock
    {
        get { return _objectMock; }
    }

    public T Build()
    {
        return _objectMock.Object; 
    }
}
```

And here is an example interface and its concrete builder that inherrits the generic one:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Bar();
}

public class FooBuilder: GenericMockBuilder<IFoo>
{
    public FooBuilder WithBar(int barValue)
    {
        base.ObjectMock.Setup(x => x.Bar()).Returns(barValue);
        return this;
    }

}
```

The builder will construct a foo mock like this:

```
        IFoo fooMock = new FooBuilder().WithBar(12).Build();
```

I would love to hear oppinions and suggestions for improvement.

**EDIT (Eventraising example added):**

```
public class FooBuilderWithEvent: GenericMockBuilder<IFoo>
{

    public FooBuilderWithEvent RaiseEvent(FooEventArgs fooEventArgs)
    {
        base.ObjectMock.Raise(m => m.FooEvent += null, fooEventArgs); 
        return this; 
    }

}
```

Building Mock and raising event would look like this:

```
        FooBuilderWithEvent fooBuilderWithEvent = new FooBuilderWithEvent(); 
        IFoo fooMock = fooBuilderWithEvent.Build();

        //Create testobject and prepare for event here

        fooBuilderWithEvent.RaiseEvent(new FooEventArgs());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*pros*

- Nice domain-specific fluent interface

*cons*

- Another interface, which nobody familiar with (me, and I think many other developers do not see anything complex on mock setup with standard fluent interface of Moq)
- Creating builder class for each mocked interface (yes, you can create builders only for complex mocks, but using of two different mocking interfaces could confuse developers)
- Creating setup method for each mocked member

Don't know why you are asking for Moq sample, because you already have all this code inside builder:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Bar()).Returns(42);
```

If lambdas and `mock.Object` calls are confusing to you, try RhinoMocks:

```
Exect.Call(foo.Bar()).Return(42);
```

Also I have a question - *how are you going to raise events* with only mocked object instance?

Comment: Maybe I am just not that fluent in Moq yet. I find it hard to produce one-liner construction with Moq that reads almost like prose, which this pattern does. I like test data construction to take as little space as possible in the test. Can you give an example of compact fluent test data creation with Moq?

Comment: Thanks... Regarding event raising: I'll have to look into that

Comment: ... Looked into it: As I see it, I would have to raise events from the builder. Thus, the builder would have a RaiseEvent method. This means holding on to the builder after creating the mock.  See edit for example

Answer (score 0):

Having to build a facade over the mocking framework indicates that it's not right for you. Why not try another one. I personally have switched from Moq to NSubstitute:

Your own example:

```
IFoo fooMock = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
fooMock.WithBar(12).Returns(10);
```

Or if you only want to check that the method is called:

```
//arrange
IFoo fooMock = Substitute.For<IFoo>(); 

//act
fooMock.WithBar(12);

//assert
fooMock.Received().WithBar(12);
```

Comment: The first code snippet here will not compile. Returns(..) is a `void` method.